# How to Build a String in DRL file

Tags: drools

```
String i;    
String j;    
String k;    

i.concat(j).concat(k);
```

Now I want to write this in DRL file.

```
rule "X"

    when 
          xx : X(i.concat(j).concat(k))
```

I am new with Drools, please help me to build the string inside the when condition in DRL file.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? The "when" clause if for checking conditions, not manipulating values.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any good reason to want to do this. The "when" clause is for checking conditions (broadly equivalent to an "if" statement.)

Now, assuming you have some input object X that looks like this:

```
class X {
  String i;
  String j;
  String k;
}
```

... you can create a String that's the concatenated form of the `i`, `j` and `k` values in a few ways.

One way would be like this:

```
rule "Str from x - v1"
when
  X( $i: i, $j: j, $k: k )
  $str: String() from $i.concat($j).concat($k)
then
  // do something with $str
end
```

If you're just trying to compare to the concatenated value, you could just, you know, concatenate the fields at the time of comparison instead of assigning them to a variable:

```
rule "Just compare it"
when
  X( $i: i, $j: j, $k: k )
  SomethingElse( myStr == $i + $j + $k )
then
  // ...
end
```

Since `$i`, `$j`, and `$k` values are immutable (since they're Strings), you can concatenate them at any time and always get the same result, so it's not even a case of "the values might change from under me". So while there's very little reason to ever do this, here's how you'd go about it.